# A function of x next to an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Today my calculus teacher said that if you have an integral, you cannot multiply it by a function of x, or in other words you cannot have a function coefficient of an integral, even if that function cancels out to be 1. For example, she said that although it does not change the value, you cannot have $\displaystyle \frac{e^x}{e^x}\int f(x) dx$. Why aren't you allowed to do this since it doesn't change the value? Please keep your answer in more simplified terms since I'm only in calculus 1. Thanks!

Comment: You can see that you perfectly well can.

Comment: Yes, the expression you wrote doesn't break any rules.

Comment: There is nothing "forbidden" in writing $g(x)\int f(x)dx$, whatever $f,g$. Are you sure you are telling us the whole story ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust This was 4 years ago when I was still in highschool, so I no longer care what the teacher said because I know now what I can and can't do. But as far as I remember, I told the whole story. I was just as surprised and incredulous as you when I heard it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your teacher may have intended to say that you cannot do the following

$$\int f(x)\,dx=\frac{e^x}{e^x}\int f(x)\,dx\stackrel{\text{this step is terribly wrong!}}=\frac{1}{e^x}\int e^x\,f(x)\,dx$$

What you can do is multiply it by a *constant* (with respet to $\,x\,$) value:

$$\int f(x)\,dx=\frac{k}{k}\int f(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{k}\int kf(x)\,dx\;\;,\;\;\;k\neq 0$$

Comment: DonAntonio I don't think it was that mistake because I specifically wrote exactly this integral down and she said she knows that it doesn't make sense because e^x/e^x simplifies to 1, but you are still not allowed to do it.

Comment: Well, then I'm afraid that teacher was talking nonsense since *any* mathematical expression  multipled by one remains the same...at least in the usual mathematics.